# SQL Server : set user to only SEE 1 database, and only some views. (not just deny access, so they can't see at all)

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to set up a user in SQL Server 2008 R2 so when they login, they only see one database and so they only see views with 1 schema.

They should not be able to see that other databases exist, that any tables exist within the database that they can see, or any views that exist other than tables that belong to one schema.

How can I go about doing this?

Thank you in advance

Edit: some more information. I have managed to get a user to only see 1 database and no others in the past by denying view all databases and making the user the owner of the database.  In this case the user can not be the owner of the database.

Comment: All I have done is google so far. I have tried to have a user only be able to SEE(not just deny looking into, but only be able to see that one DB exists) one database in the past, and the only way I could accomplish this that I found was making them the DB owner and deny see all databases but I can not have them the DB owner in this case. I have been searching but so far have not found any information on how to accomplish what I want.

Comment: Not really a programming question though, is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the database to a new instance.